# Installing AODV protocol on Raspberry pi (https://github.com/erimatnor/aodv-uu)

Tags: c, linux, git, networking, protocols

I'm trying to install AODV protocol on Raspberry pi. After completing git clone from "https://github.com/erimatnor/aodv-uu" when I tried to do "make" and I am getting below error. Expecting your suggestion. Thank you!

> make
>   gcc -Wall -O3 -g -DDEBUG -DCONFIG_GATEWAY  -DDEBUG -o aodvd main.o list.o debug.o timer_queue.o aodv_socket.o aodv_hello.o aodv_neighbor.o aodv_timeout.o routing_table.o seek_list.o aodv_rreq.o aodv_rrep.o aodv_rerr.o nl.o locality.o
>   aodv_neighbor.o: In function `neighbor_add':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/aodv_neighbor.c:68: undefined reference to`hello_update_timeout'
>   aodv_timeout.o: In function `route_discovery_timeout':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/aodv_timeout.c:98: undefined reference to`rt_table_update_timeout'
>   aodv_rreq.o: In function `rreq_route_discovery':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/aodv_rreq.c:460: undefined reference to`rt_table_update_timeout'
>   aodv_rreq.o: In function `rreq_local_repair':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/aodv_rreq.c:521: undefined reference to`rt_table_update_timeout'
>   aodv_rrep.o: In function `rrep_forward':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/aodv_rrep.c:231: undefined reference to`rt_table_update_timeout'
>   nl.o: In function `nl_kaodv_callback':
>   /home/pi/aodv-uu/nl.c:282: undefined reference to`rt_table_update_timeout'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:112: recipe for target 'aodvd' failed
>   make: *** [aodvd] Error 1

Comment: It looks like that project hasn't seen any activity since 2011.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am getting same from "https://sourceforge.net/projects/aodvuu/". @larsks

Answer (score 0):

The code available from sourceforge is the same code that is on github.  If you download the archive, you'll see that the latest modification date of any file there is 2010.  Given the age of this code, I wouldn't be surprised to find that things simply don't work anymore.

However, here's a quick workaround for your problem.  The root cause appears to be that the problem functions, like `rt_table_update_timeout`, are declared as `inline`, but that information seems to get lost somewhere in the build process such that other object files are trying to reference these as non-inline functions.

You can avoid this by opening `defs.h`, looking for this line:

```
#define NS_INLINE inline
```

And replace it with:

```
#define NS_INLINE
```

This will allow `aodvd` to compile correctly (`make aodvd`).  On my system, the kernel module will subsequently fail to compile:

```
cc1: fatal error: /lib/modules/4.13.15-100.fc25.x86_64/build/include/linux/modversions.h: No such file or directory
```

As far as I can tell, the `modversions.h` file is no longer produced by modern Linux kernels.

Comment: hi thanks @larsks, after following your instruction I got below error also:

cc1: fatal error: /lib/modules/4.9.59-v7+/build/include/linux/modversions.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'kaodv-mod.o' failed
make[1]: *** [kaodv-mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/aodv-uu-0.9.5/lnx'
Makefile:124: recipe for target 'kaodv' failed
make: *** [kaodv] Error 2